# How do I exit a loop without using a break statement?

Tags: c, break

```
int count = 0;
// read characters from the standard input
while ((count != max_string_length) && (string[count] = getchar())) {
    // until a newline or EOF reached
    if ((string[count] == '\n' || string[count] == EOF)) {
        string[count] = 0;
        break;
    }
    count++;
}
```

This is my code, It reads a string from standard input and returns the length of the string, and the string terminates and ignores either EOF or a newline (\n) characters. However, I'm not allowed to use a break statement, I'm wondering if is there a way to exit the loop without using a break statement.

Comment: Add another variable set to 0 and check in the loop condition if it isn't 0. When you want to exit set it to a non zero value and continue so the loop condition is checked again.

Comment: you sure that string will contain EOF which is `int` vaue

Comment: This is sort of like asking, "Is there a way to drive nails, without using a hammer?"  There is: in a pinch, you can bang them in with a brick, if you don't have a hammer — but it's not the best way.  And in programming, the analogy breaks down, because there's no such thing as a compiler without a `break` statement available.

Comment: Now, it's possible you've been told you can't use `break` because `break` is like `goto`, and gotos are bad, so if you can't use gotos, you can't use `break` either.  In that case, the usual way is to add an extra boolean control variable, which you test in your `while` statement, and set or clear inside the loop, at the spot where you would have wanted to use `break`.  In my opinion, this is potentially *more* confusing and error-prone than the forbidden `break` or `goto`, but if you're dealing with someone who says Thou Shalt Not Use `break`, this will probably placate them.

Comment: The question states "without using a break", so it is allowed to use the old and hated "goto" ?

Comment: Only zealots and their adherents *hate* `goto`.  There are usually clearer alternatives, but occasionally `goto` is the clearest and cleanest way to do the job, and nobody who wants good code should have any qualms about `goto`s in those cases.

Comment: Given `string[count] = getchar()` and `string[count] == EOF`, `string` had better be an array of `int` values.  If it's an array of `char`, the code is fundamentally broken.  `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, and `EOF` is a value that can not fit into a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

> ... is there a way to exit the loop without using a break statement (?)

Yes.  Perform all 3 tests in the loop's controlling expression and none in the body of the loop.  No loop test needed in the loop's body.

- Save the 257 different response values of `getchar()` into an `int` to maintain the value's distinctiveness.
- Append a *null character* after the loop.
- Use `size_t` rather than `int` to handle all possible string sizes.

A more typical read line example code:

```
// int count = 0;
size_t count = 0;
int ch;

while ((count < max_string_length) && ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
  string[count++] = ch;
}

string[count] = `\0`;
```

If the limit represents the *size* of the buffer and not its *maximum length* as returned from `strlen()`, use a better name and alternate code.

```
while ((count + 1 < string_size) && ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least five ways to exit a loop.

One is that iteration statements contain their own built-in test for ending the loop. So the desired condition for ending the loop can be built into that test, provided the exit is desired at the start or end of a loop body. (To exit at the start of the loop body, use a `while` or `for` statement, which test the controlling expression before each iteration. To exit at the end of the loop body, use a `do … while` statement, which test the expression after each iteration.)

Clause 6.8.6 of the 2018 C standard lists the jump statements, three of which can be used to exit a loop:

- `goto identifier ;`
- `continue ;`
- `break ;`
- `return expressionopt ;`

The `continue;` statement exits the current iteration but continues the loop, which is not what you want, and you are prohibited from using `break;`, so that leaves the other two, `goto` and `return`.

To use `goto` simply put a label after the loop and `goto` that label:

```
while ((count != max_string_length) && (string[count] = getchar()))
{
    if ((string[count] == '\n' || string[count] == EOF))
        goto EndOfLoop;
    ++count;
}
EndOfLoop:
// Some other statement. (Cannot be declaration or end of routine.  Can be plain `;`.)
```

To use a `return`, you would need to isolate the loop in its own function, so that returning from the function ends only the loop and not other code in the original function. This is infrequently done for a single loop, as the `break` statement usually suffices, but it is a reasonable way to handle nested loops, where a `break` would exit only the inner loop but you want to exit all of them.

A fifth way to exit a loop is to use certain of the standard library routines, such as `longjmp` after an initial `setjmp`. However, these are special-purpose routines to save and restore program state and are generally overkill for merely exiting a loop. Other library routines that could technically exit a loop are also overkill: `exit` and other routines in C 2018 7.22.4, `thrdexit` to exit a thread, and the signal raise function `raise`.

So the most appropriate solutions for your situation are to build the test into the loop’s controlling expression, to use `goto`, or to isolate the loop in its own function and use `return`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have the loop

```
while(condition) {
    statements;
    if(break_condition) break;
    more_statements;
}
```

you can transform it into this alternative loop, without a `break`:

```
int early_exit = 0;
while(condition && !early_exit) {
    statements;
    if(break_condition)
        early_exit = 1;
    else {
        more_statements;
    }
}
```

The only problem here is that the extra `early_exit` variable is a perfect example of what some people call a "spaghetti Boolean".

To explain:

Everyone knows that gotos are bad, although what's really true is that arbitrary, unconstrained use of gotos is bad.  A single well-intentioned `goto` can be perfectly clear, but unconstrained use of gotos tends to lead to "spaghetti code", with control flow that wanders all over the place and is impossible to follow.

But, a `goto` is not the only way to alter control flow, particularly in a loop.  As I've shown in this example, a Boolean variable like `early_exit` can also be used to alter control flow.  The problem is that if you're not careful, you end up with Boolean variables that are set and cleared and tested all over the place, and are impossible  to follow — thus the pejorative term, "spaghetti Booleans".

Trying to achieve clear control flow is a good and noble goal.  However, trying to enforce it with blanket rules like "don't use `goto`" or "don't use `break`" tends to be counterproductive.  If you haven't learned good techniques for writing complicated control flow structures clearly, if you've been told that you simply mustn't use `break` or `goto`, it's all too easy to come up with a piece of code that, yes, doesn't use `break` or `goto` but still, no, isn't at all clear to a later reader.

In many cases, the clear, easy, nonconfusing way to achieve an early exit from a lop is: with a `break` statement.  The whole point of `break` (and its cousin `continue`) is that they are *constrained* forms of `goto`, specifically designed to be less confusing, and difficult to misuse.  People who say that "`break` and `continue` are gotos in disguise and therefore shouldn't be used" are, in my opinion, missing the point.  And, in any case, it seems to me that a rule that merely forces the replacement of one kind of spaghetti with another is pretty much self-defeating.

Answer (score 0):

To check for EOF you need to save the result of `getchar` in `int` variable. If `string` can accommodate `max_string_length` characters (including null terminating character) you need to check where to place the null terminating character.

```
    size_t count = 0;
    int c;
    // read characters from the standard input
    while ((count < max_string_length - 1) && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') 
    {
        string[count++] = c;
    }
    
    string[count] = 0;
```

Comment: Corner concern:  `count < max_string_length - 1` almost the same as `count + 1 < max_string_length` unless a `max_string_length == 0`.  Then it is like `count < SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: it is not a whole code. `max_string_length >= 0` assuming that it is `int` as other variables in the OPs code should be done earlier in the code (string has to be allocated somehow). Otherwise, we need to check for `string` as well

Comment: Even if `max_string_length` is an `int`, compare `count < max_string_length - 1` uses _unsigned_ math as this answer uses `size_t count`.  Corner `max_string_length == 0` remains a problem.